# C#, check whether integer array has negative numbers in it

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a array `int[] numArray` . I want to know is there any straight forward way to just check whether array has negative numbers in it ?

If there is no direct method even linq will do . I am bit new to linq . Can anyone suggest ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336759.aspx#anySimple):

```
bool containsNegative = numArray.Any(i => i < 0)
```

Or

```
bool containsNegative = numArray.Min() < 0;
```

---

EDIT

```
int[] negativeNumbers = numArray.Where(i => i < 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: How do i retrieve all negative numbers through linq ?

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory: Any() looks like a better solution than Min(), since Any() returns true upon finding the first negative element, while Min() always loops through the entire array. You might want to indicate this in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you're open to using LINQ:

```
var containsNegatives = numArray.Any(n => n < 0);
```

Or, if you want to do it the "old fashioned" way...you just have to loop:

```
var containsNegatives = false;

foreach(var n in numArray)
{
    if(n < 0)
    {
        containsNegatives = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

And if you really want to get fancy, you could turn that into an Extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsNegatives(this IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        foreach(n in numbers)
        {
            if(n < 0) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And call it from your code like:

```
var containsNegatives = numArray.ContainsNegatives();
```

Comment: Or you could wrap *old fashioned* way in Extension method, and use it like LINQ.

Comment: @gor - Haha...funny that you made the comment while I was adding that to the answer. Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
var negativeExist = numArray.Any(a => a < 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.Find(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa.aspx) method to perform this task.

```
public static T Find<T>(
    T[] array,
    Predicate<T> match
)
```

For example,

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create an array of five Point structures.
        Point[] points = { new Point(100, 200), 
            new Point(150, 250), new Point(250, 375), 
            new Point(275, 395), new Point(295, 450) };

        // To find the first Point structure for which X times Y 
        // is greater than 100000, pass the array and a delegate
        // that represents the ProductGT10 method to the static 
        // Find method of the Array class. 
        Point first = Array.Find(points, ProductGT10);

        // Note that you do not need to create the delegate 
        // explicitly, or to specify the type parameter of the 
        // generic method, because the C# compiler has enough
        // context to determine that information for you.

        // Display the first structure found.
        Console.WriteLine("Found: X = {0}, Y = {1}", first.X, first.Y);
    }

    // This method implements the test condition for the Find
    // method.
    private static bool ProductGT10(Point p)
    {
        if (p.X * p.Y > 100000)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

/* This code example produces the following output:

Found: X = 275, Y = 395
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Traditional:

```
foreach (int number in numArray) { if (number < 0) return true; }
return false;
```

With LINQ:

```
bool result = numArray.Any(x => x < 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit twidling version would be

```
public static bool AnyNegative(int[] arr){
  const long firstBit = 2147483648;
  var res = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length && !res; i++) res = (arr[i] & firstBit) == firstBit;
  return res;
}
```

you can the call it like this>

```
int arr = {...}
  if(arr.AnyNegative()){
      //do stuf if there's any negative numbers
  }
```

of course this is just an obfuscated version of

```
public static bool AnyNegative(int[] arr){
            var res = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length && !res; i++) res = arr[i] < 0;
            return res;
}
```

Comment: there is no need to loop through all items. You can return when you find the first negative item.

Comment: @BalaR which is why the code I've posted exits after finding the first

Comment: Ah, I missed the `!res` in the loop contition. Not used to looking conditions like that up there.